# In pyspark rdd how to run a function for each element and update an external variable depending upon them?

Tags: python, pyspark, foreach, rdd

I want to update an external variable depending upon the elements of an rdd.

For the following code:

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()

rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4]) #creating rdd

FLAG = False #initialized to False

def fun(x):
  global FLAG
  print(x)
  FLAG = True #when this function executes I expect this variable to be set to True

rdd.foreach(fun) #this calls above function for each element

print(FLAG) #But this prints False still.
```

Can anyone explain to me why that FLAG variable is not being set to True?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? I mean, when to change from False to True?

Comment: When I iterate over the elements of that rdd using foreach() [or any other appropriate function] i want the value of FLAG to change.